# Files.walk() OS-independency issue

Tags: java, nio2

I have the following code which works fine under Linux/Unix:

```
Files.walk(Paths.get(getStartingPath()))
     .filter(Files::isDirectory)
     // Skip directories which start with a dot (like, for example: .index)
     .filter(path -> !path.toAbsolutePath().toString().matches(".*/\\..*"))
     // Note: Sorting can be expensive:
     .sorted()
     .forEach(operation::execute);
```

However, under Windows, this part seems to not work properly:

```
     .filter(path -> !path.toAbsolutePath().toString().matches(".*/\\..*"))
```

What would be the proper way to make this OS-independent?

Comment: Can't test this, so I'll use comment: Instead of '/' use File.separator. matches(".*" + File.separator + "\\..*")

Comment: I'd already tried that, but it doesn't work, because it needs to be escaped. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not match the `Path` against hard-coded file separators. This is bound to cause problems.

What you want here is a way to get the name of the directory and skip it if it starts with a dot. You can retrieve the name of the directory with [`getFileName()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#getFileName--):

> Returns the name of the file or directory denoted by this path as a `Path` object. The file name is the *farthest* element from the root in the directory hierarchy.

Then you can use [`startsWith(".")`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#startsWith-java.lang.String-) to see if it starts with a dot or not.

As such, you could have

```
.filter(path -> !path.getFileName().startsWith("."))
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution to what @Tunaki suggests is to try replacing the forward slash with the OS-specific file separator (you will need to escape it in case it is the backslash character on Windows):

```
.filter(path -> 
        !path.toAbsolutePath().toString().matches(".*"
                                        + Pattern.quote(File.separator) + "\\..*"))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! :)